# Yahoo Finance API Commodity Prices

Tags: yahoofinance

I´m working on a stock app for iOS where I´m overlaying the diagram with the historical prices of a stock and the prices of the only commodity this company is producing. The commodities I'm interested in are **iron ore**, **copper**, **nickl** and **potash**.

For the stock prices I use Yahoo Finance API which is really easy to use. But now I have a problem:

I can´t find an API where I can get the historical data from different raw materials in .csv or .json. I read through the description of the API of worldbank.org but it´s not clear how to create a URL where I get the data from.

Does someone know a API to get this data from or a way to get it from the Yahoo Finance API?

Thanks a lot

N.F.M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that'd help but usually [Index Mundi](http://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/) is a good source for physical commodities.